# target inputs with same name different forms on 1 page with php

Tags: php, forms, input

Basically I have multiple forms on 1 page (all taking different data), but I want to use the same bit of php to gather the values from a form's inputs with this type of method:

```
if(isset($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title'])){
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
}
```

Is it possible to get multiple forms to use the same php "if" statement, where the input values are assigned to variables, only from the submitted form in question?

Comment: Only the submitted form.

Comment: You can only really submit one form at a time. If this is what you want and you just want to use the same PHP code to process whichever one is submitted, just assign the same `name` attribute to the fields that need to be processed the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript or jQuery with hidden input fields to keep the data in all of your forms synced and able to submit together.

### Example Code

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" />
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[id^="form"] input[type="text"]').on('change', function(e) {
    var fieldName = $(this).attr('name');
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    $('[name="' + fieldName + '"][type="hidden"]').val(newValue);
});
```

That *SHOULD* be corrent.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have different forms, or just one form with multiple inputs?

In both variants, it's possible. Your code just reads what got send via POST.

I think your problem could be solved by merging all those inputs into one form.

The problem is actually getting all the data sent at ONCE (when hitting your php). Since a submit button submits the whole form, you avoid this.